# Стандартные библиотеки для GUI в C++

Tags: c++, gui

Перехожу с *Java* на *C++*. В *Java* были стандартные библиотеки типа *AWT*, *Swing*, *JavaFX* для создания пользовательских интерфейсов.

Что для этого есть в *C++*?

Comment: Qt :) wxWidgets и т.д.

Comment: Смотря что понимать под "стандартной библиотекой". Встроенных в язык - нет. Широко распространенные кросс- и не кросс-платформенные - достаточно. Я бы смотрел в сторону Qt.

Comment: C++ вообще очень консервативный язык. Там до сих пор нет даже средств управления консолью (наподобие «узнать ширину консольного окна» или там «ввести символ без отображения»), т. к. считалось, что программа на C++ имеет право бежать на устройствах без дисплея, а вы уж сразу о GUI!

Comment: Консоль, как средство вывода информации - конечно сильно уступает GUI по деталям. Но не по принципу. С/С++ в этом плане - было на правильном пути. Имхо. Сперва - стандартизация, потом - реализация. Задаемся вопросом: у нас есть стандартизация "терминала"?

Answer (score 13):

В С++ нет **стандартных** библиотек для GUI.

Есть библиотеки сторонних разработчиков, типа: Qt, wxWidgets, JUCE, Nana, eGUI, etc. А так же собственные решения от Microsoft, Borland (ныне Embarcadero Technologies).

Answer (score 10):

На текущий момент стандартных библиотек для графики действительно нет в C++. Нужно использовать сторонние, [список](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_platform-independent_GUI_libraries#C_.2F_C.2B.2B_packages) можно посмотреть на википедии. Но уже сейчас есть соответствующее предложение о добавлении такого функционала и в стандартную часть.

Например, на [странице](https://isocpp.org/std/status) сайта, посвящённого стандартизации C++ есть такая картинка (см. нижний правый угол):

> [image: 2D graphics]

Черновик предложения, озаглавленный как *"A Proposal to Add 2D Graphics
Rendering and Display to C++"* содержит на текущий момент 227 (!) страниц и доступен по [ссылке](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0267r2.pdf).

Comment: Интересно еще, чего там по нетворкингу замутят? Наверняка более определеннее GUI.